# zf2 extend existing modules

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've been working with zf2 for a while but i could not get a solution for the following problem.

eg. we have a module called "Product" which handle the most of the product stuff.
Another module - let's call it "Review" - should extend the Product module and extend the product view to offer a product review to the user.

Until this point there seems to be no problem. We can easily overwrite the product view in the Review module.

Now the tricky part where i got stuck.
There's a third module - let's call it "Social". This module should provide social functioniality to the whole application.
This module should also modify the product view and add a link in the product page called "EMail to a friend".

Now my problem...
The product view is modified by the review module. If i overwrite the view in the Social module, the changes from the Review module are lost.

// Edit
Info: The Social and Review module should be able to modify the views WITHOUT modifiing the Product module.

Any tips, hints or ideas are welcome.

Comment: Assuming it's okay for the modules to be dependent on each other, is there a reason why you can't just modify the product view to call a view helper for reviews, and another view helper for social links?

Comment: Sure, under this assumption everything would be fine. But i dont want to modify the product module for this, because i want to avoid cycle dependencies.

Comment: Then you should create a new module within an own product view to call view helper like Tim Fountain suggested. But i cannot recognize cycle dependencies by adding view helpers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what code you are trying to avoid duplicating.

If it's just HTML content you can [create a custom `ViewHelper`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#view-helpers) to render the required HTML. This could then be reused within each view that needs the "social" content.

I suspect however you are reffering to the a 'social' controller action and you wish to reuse the return result of that within other views. If so, one soultion would be to use the [`forward()` controller plugin](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#forward-plugin).

From the documentation:

> Occasionally, you may want to dispatch additional controllers from within the matched controller – for instance, you might use this approach to build up “widgetized” content. The Forward plugin helps enable this [by] returning the results of the dispatched controller action

This is useful in a situation like yours as you require the "Social" module to be an additional element of the view; rather than a replacement.

For example

```
// SocialModule\Controller\SocialController.php
// Controller action to display social buttons (twitter/facebook etc)
public function socialAction()
{
    // Some controller logic...

    // Returns the social button view
    return new ViewModel(array('foo' => $bar));
}

// ProductModule\Controller\ProductController.php
public function productViewAction()
{
    $product = $this->productService->find($this->params('id'));

    // Displays the product 'view' page
    $view = new ViewModel(array(
        'product' => $product,
    ));

    // Re-disptach the social module action and return it's view model
    $socialView = $this->forward()->dispatch('SocialModule\Controller\Social', array(
        'action'  => 'social',
    ));

    // We now have the view model, attach it to our view
    $view->addChild($socialView, 'social');

    // Return the aggregated view
    return $view;
}
```

All then is required is to render the content in the view

```
// product-view.phtml
echo $this->social;
```

Comment: Sounds good, but this requires a change in the ProductController and will result in a cycle dependency. SocialModule requires ProductModule and ProductModule (ProductController::productViewAction) requires the SocialModule. I'm not sure if the solution that i want is possible with zf2 at all.